# Append new string to cell in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying this, but it's not working:

```
Sub macro1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim LR As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For r = 2 To LR

p = Application.Match(Cells(r, 3), Sheets("Input").Range("C:C"), 0)

If IsError(p) Then GoTo nextr:

Cells(r, 4).Value = .Value & ",newsletter" '***here***


nextr:
Next r

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If I use the following on the line marked ***here*** :

```
Cells(r,4) = "Y"
```

It works, so I guess I've done my append wrong?

Comment: In line `Cells(r, 4).Value = .Value & ",newsletter"`, ".Value" is for what? I means value of what.

Comment: I'm an idiot! This works: Cells(r, 4).Value = Cells(r, 4).Value & ",newsletter"

Answer (score 0):

Just to spell out the answer and to format it nicely:

```
Option Explicit

Sub macro1()
Dim p As Double
Dim LR As Long
Dim r As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

LR = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To LR
    p = Application.Match(Cells(r, 3), Sheets("Input").Range("C:C"), 0)
    If Not IsError(p) Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 4).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 4).Value & ",newsletter" '***here***
    End If
Next r

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```